# How do I create a local account (non-admin) but still have access to XBL and Store account?

Tags: windows-8

Pretty much exactly what the title says.  I want to have a non-admin local account that can still access X-Box Live and my Store account.  Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try creating a non-admin account and it wasn't able to install apps from the store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Run secpol.msc (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> > type `secpol.msc` > press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Double-click **Application Control Policies** then double-click **AppLocker**,
- Right click on **Packaged app Rules** and click **Create Default Rules**

[image: Create Default Rules]

This will create one rule that allows all packaged apps to run for all users.

[image: Result]

You can follow this lengthy www.grouppolicy.biz [tutorial](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/08/how-manage-published-a-k-a-metro-apps-in-windows-8-using-group-policy/) if you want to block specific apps.

Sources:
[technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878535.aspx),
[www.grouppolicy.biz](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2012/08/how-manage-published-a-k-a-metro-apps-in-windows-8-using-group-policy/)

Comment: Uhhh, how does that solve his problem?

Comment: Edited my answer, now it's not as useless as it was.